# MagnificPopup, инит после загрузки страницы

Tags: jquery, popup

Да, вопрос был этот уже несколько раз "инициализация попап после загрузки страницы", но в чем проблема, все как в документации

```
<section class="form-answer mfp-hide" style="" id="sendOk">

<img src="<?= $okImg["SRC"] ?>" alt="">
<div class="form-answer__title"><?= $resOk["PROPERTY_SUCCSES_POPUP_TITLE_VALUE"] ?></div>
<div class="form-answer__text"><?= $resOk["PROPERTY_SUCCSES_POPUP_CONTENT_VALUE"] ?></div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sendOk').magnificPopup({type: 'inline'});
});
```